# Inseting data into new table - SQL - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Ok, I have tried various things, cant get data inserted.
Look at my code, what am I doing wrong?
(it's been suggested that I dont use quotes on the number fields, that doesn't work......

DESC TABLE

```
SQL> DESC BW_CLASS
 Name
 -----------------------
 CLASS_ID
 CLASS_NAME
 PROFESSOR
 NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS
 COST
 START_DATE
 END_DATE
 ROOM_NUM
```

What I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO BW_CLASS 
VALUES
(‘PC101’, ‘MS OFFICE BASICS’, ‘INDIANA JONES’,’18’,’1000’,
TO_DATE('01-10-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
TO_DATE('05-10-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
‘1276’);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting? You had wrong apostrophes signs around your values, try this:

```
INSERT INTO BW_CLASS VALUES (
  'PC101', 'MS OFFICE BASICS', 'INDIANA JONES', 18, 1000,
  TO_DATE('01-10-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
  TO_DATE('05-10-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
  1276);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quotes, do I use the single quote, or the hash mark on the tilde key? What did I do wrong? Thank you for your help !

Comment: @BrianWilson You should just use the single quote character that's on the keyboard near the 'Enter' key - the second to the left of it. In your code, you used some other characters that are available in, I guess, Word or some other text editor. Use Notepad++, SQLDeveloper or some IDE.

Comment: Thanks again, for multiple entries, I replace the ';' w/ a comma and enter the data again, formatted same as before, correct?